# jquery: fix first misfire of if()

Tags: javascript, jquery

My js fiddle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/brvnhg1w/

(Please run the above fiddle first) If you double click the  three dots it turns into a textbox, once you click out of press enter it goes back to being text. That works fine.

I want to do an update in the DB via an ajax call if the text has changed, but the first time you change the text (eg: from the three dots to, for example, "111") if you look in the console it says "unchanged" instead of "changed" and if you look at this line: `console.log("Id: "+this.id+ " Value: " +this.value+ " OldValue:" +v );` thats gets printed in the console, for some reason it takes the new value and gets prints it as the prev value :(

So basically: if I have my ajax code in the "changed" part, the first time the client changes the textbox - it wont to fire... :(

The problem seems to be in this part of the code:

```
  var n = prev.ix.indexOf(this.id);
  var v=prev.val[n];


  if(this.value!=v){
      //value changed
      console.log("changed");
      prev.val[n]=this.value;//update existing value

      // do .ajax - update the DB

  }else{
      console.log("unchanged");
  }
console.log("Id: "+this.id+ " Value: " +this.value+ " OldValue:" +v );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is when you check if the current input is in your array, you set the value. So once you hit the condition, the value will always be the same the first time.

To counter that, instead of pushing a value in the array, push an empty string `''`:

```
  if($.inArray(this.id,prev.ix) == -1){
      prev.ix.push(this.id);
      prev.val.push('');
  }
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/brvnhg1w/5/

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! I didn't catch it as I'm a noob and another person helped me with the original code...

Comment: Oops, spoke a bit soon, now if a person clicks the box, then clicks away without changing anything, its supposed to go back to its original state, it does not, it still says "changed"

Comment: @Ryan well, instead of undefined, push an empty string : `.push('')`

Answer (score 1):

When the function first fires (and every subsuquent time) you are pushing the values into your arrays in `prev`. But that is the array the value is being compared against, so it compares the first value to itself and logs 'unchanged'. You might have to code an edge case for the initial run:

```
var n = prev.ix.indexOf(this.id);
var v=prev.val[n];
var flag = true;

if(this.value!=v || flag){
    //value changed
    console.log("changed");
    prev.val[n]=this.value;//update existing value

    // do .ajax - update the DB
    //set flag to false, initial run over
    flag = false;

}else{
    console.log("unchanged");
}
```

console.log("Id: "+this.id+ " Value: " +this.value+ " OldValue:" +v );

http://jsfiddle.net/5eru6mt2/1/

Comment: Where do I put that? Can you place it in the original fiddle and give me the link please? I'm a noob and understanding this stuff is a bit hard

Comment: Injected my code into yours from the posted question. The `if` will trigger on the initial run, get set to `false`, and then the function should work as you intended.